# Comparação de horas em Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

Estou tentando criar um método que vai retornar a quantidade de minutos desde a ultima inserção no banco. A maneira que fiz foi essa, mas esta dando erro:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$minutes = LusLeadUpdateStatus::select('created_at')
     ->orderby ('created_at', 'desc')
     ->get()
     ->toArray();

$totalDuration = $minutes->diffInMinutes($now);
(// o erro é aqui, pois dando print_r($minutes) o resultado é algo assim:
    [0] => Array
    (
        [created_at] => 2018-08-30 14:55:35
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [created_at] => 2018-08-30 14:55:20
    )
)
```

o campo created_at é onde tenho a inserção no banco, e ele esta com o formato data / hora.

Comment: Experimenta: `$minutes = LusLeadUpdateStatus::select('created_at')
     ->orderby ('created_at', 'desc')
     ->first()`, e depois de inicializares `$totalDuration` como estás a fazer vê o retorno de  `dd($totalDuration);`

Answer (score 6):

Esta foi a resposta final que consegui(funcionando corretamente):

```
$lusLeadUpdateStatus = LusLeadUpdateStatus::select('created_at')
            ->orderby('created_at', 'desc')
            ->first();

        if ($lusLeadUpdateStatus) {
            $now = Carbon::now();

            $lastDateTime = $lusLeadUpdateStatus->toArray();
            $lastDateTime = $lastDateTime['created_at'];

            return $now->diffInMinutes($lastDateTime);
        }
        return false;
```